# Android - Convert URL to File

Tags: android, android-file

I have a URL like this:

```
String url = "https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/t1/226654_10200335941702035_1975023945_n.jpg"
```

I want to convert this url to the file and I tried this:

```
fileName = new URL(url);

sourceFile = new File(fileName.getFile());
```

also i tried:

```
sourceFile = new File(fileName.getPath());
```

but both did not work for me. What should be done?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use glide library to get bitmap of url:

> ```
> Glide.with(activity).load(imagePath).asBitmap().into(object :SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(){
>                 override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap?, glideAnimation: GlideAnimation<in Bitmap>?) {
>
>
>                      val file= GetFileFromBitmap().getFileFromBitmap(resource!!,activity)!!)
>
>
>                 }
>
>             })
> ```

2. To convert bitmap to file:

> ```
> class GetFileFromBitmap
> {
>     fun getFileFromBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap,context: Context) : File?
>     {
>         val cache = context.externalCacheDir
>         val shareFile = File(cache, "myFile.jpg")
>         Log.d("share file type is", shareFile.absolutePath)
>         try {
>             val out = FileOutputStream(shareFile)
>             bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out)
>             out.flush()
>             out.close()
>             return shareFile
>         } catch (e: Exception) {
>
>         }
>         return null
>     }
> }
> ```

Note: My code is in kotlin let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `File` for network paths. You'll have to download the file before creating a `File` from it.

Answer (score 0):

You cant conevrt it directly

try this code, it workd for HTTP connection...

```
   File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
}
```

f is your output file..

Comment: FileCache fileCache = new FileCache(context);

Comment: Read it completelty.... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: can we get the file path to upload server

Comment: file_path is used to extract the file for uploading to server. Already you have file here, then why you need file_path again??